# Java: Print Array: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to print the contents of an array using System.out.print() but I encounter this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at Polymorphism.actionPerformed(Polymorphism.java:196)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

The line the error is referring to is line 3:

```
 else if (e.getSource() == printArray) {
        for (int q=0; q<j; q++){
            System.out.print("Type: " + itemList.get(j).selectedType + "    ");
            System.out.print("Width: " + itemList.get(j).selectedWidth + "    ");
            System.out.print("Length: " + itemList.get(j).selectedLength + "    ");
    }
}
```

I don't have any debugger experience so I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are not supposed to be using get(q)?

Comment: Thanks, all solutions worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to **.get(j)** as Renjith says and you can also make sure to never end up in the situation you're in

instead of

```
for (int q=0; q<j; q++) {
```

do

```
for (int q=0; q<itemList.size(); q++) {
```

This way you cannot .get from anything larger than the size of the list/array

Comment: Thanks, all solutions worked. I preferred this one for robustness.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to wrong index I guess.

change itemList.get(j) to itemList.get(q) ;

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
        System.out.print("Type: " + itemList.get(j).selectedType + "    ");
        System.out.print("Width: " + itemList.get(j).selectedWidth + "    ");
        System.out.print("Length: " + itemList.get(j).selectedLength + "    ");
```

with

```
   System.out.print("Type: " + itemList.get(q).selectedType + "    ");
   System.out.print("Width: " + itemList.get(q).selectedWidth + "    ");
   System.out.print("Length: " + itemList.get(q).selectedLength + "    ");
```

The reason being you are iterating through the list with lookup value of List size it self.

The condition is breaking when loop index (which is always < listsize) is greater than listsize (which is 2 in this case)

Comment: Thanks, all solutions worked.

Answer (score 1):

That is a blunder!
Use:

```
else if (e.getSource() == printArray) {
        for (int q=0; q<j; q++){
            System.out.print("Type: " + itemList.get(q).selectedType + "    ");
            System.out.print("Width: " + itemList.get(q).selectedWidth + "    ");
            System.out.print("Length: " + itemList.get(q).selectedLength + "    ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using this code to print the element

```
 itemList.get(j).selectedType
```

and you need to use this

```
 itemList.get(q).selectedType
```

Answer (score 0):

If `j` is the size of your item list, `itemList.get(j)` is going to give you an index out of bounds, as a zero-based index would only go to j - 1.  It looks like you want `itemList.get(q)`, from your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a `pretty common mistake`. If you are using any `IDE like Eclipse`, you should consider learning more about the `Debug Perspective`.